# How can I log all events fired by a given DOM object?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, dom-events

Is there a way (a library) to log all the events that an HTML (or SVG) element is going trough, on the console?

I mean, I have the feeling there should be one, but I never heard of it.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Chrome, `monitorEvents` should suit your needs:

https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2015/04/quickly-monitor-events-from-the-console-panel